# Angular Form Builder

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

I'm looking for a Form Builder in Angular (preferably 6, but anything from Angular 2+ would be helpful).

The end goal will be to allow users to build a form by adding questions (fields) dynamically.

It should:

- Allow adding, removing, editing and ordering of form fields.
- Include input types: Text, select, checkbox/checkbox groups, radio, date-picker, file upload.
- Generate the form to allow fields to be filled in, and return JSON data.
- Be open source.

A couple of examples I found:

[Angular Material Form Builder](https://gcareri.github.io/angular-material-form-builder/): Has most of the functionality, but in AngularJS.

[jQuery Form Builder](https://formbuilder.online/): Has a lot of functionality, but not Angular.

I'm currently looking into [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) ([live example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz.html)), but with my current experience/knowledge of Angular/TypeScript, could take a while to build from scratch.

Thanks